# pydub doesn't not close damaged files and cannot rename the file

Tags: python, operating-system, pydub

i have some pieces of mp3 that's recovered from my damaged hard disk. then i found some of the mp3s had been damaged, but some were ok. so, i'm using the following code to filter those damaged mp3s.
`

```
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
fname= 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\1.mp3'
try:
    sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(fname)
except:
    print(fname)
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(fname)
    p, name = os.path.split(base)
    os.rename(fname, p + '\\' + name + '[damaged]' + extension)
```

`

but in the os.rename part, it prints error:`PermissionError: [WinError 32]`
it suggests that the file has been occupied by python programe.
how to solute the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this library

```
from os.path import join
```

And this for rename

```
os.rename(join(p,fname), join(p,name)+'[damaged]' + extension)
```

Comment: problem is that the mp3 file has been opened by 'AudioSegment.from_file(fname)' because when `try` captures errors(because the mp3 file is a damaged one), it won't close the mp3 file.so in the `except` part, `os.rename` cannot rename a file that's been kept opened by another programe. because of this, you even cannot rename the file mannually.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked.

```
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
fname= 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\1.mp3'
try:
    #sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(fname)
    with open(fname, "rb") as wav_file:
         sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(wav_file)except:

except:
    print(fname)
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(fname)
    p, name = os.path.split(base)
    os.rename(fname, p + '\\' + name + '[damaged]' + extension)
```

Comment: Please elaborate by placing your code in the answer, along with an explanation.